# How to store wordpress title in a variable

Tags: loop, child-theme, variables, get-the-title

trying to run a PHP youtube v3 data in a WordPress theme

```
$grab=ngegrab('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='.$devkey.'&part=snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=5&q='.$unity.'&pageToken='.$yesPage.'&type=video');
```

trying to store wp title in a variable  so it won't echo the above API URL and it seems all method have tried isn't working **&q='.$unity.'** in the above code

List I tired

**$unity = $post->post_tite;**

**the_title();**

**get_the_title();**

and even more

is there still a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're example is totally unclear. What is `ngegrab`, what is `$unity`, `$yesPage` and what do you mean with "WordPress title"? Short: what are you trying to do exactly?

To get the title of a post, use `get_the_title()` as mentioned in the other answer. To get the document title (`<title></title>`), use `wp_get_document_title()`.

Comment: **ngegrab** is what am using to collect data from that URL (youtube v3). the **unity** is what am using to call back my variable for wp post title. the $yesPage is my next page variable. am only having the issue with the **unity**  variable to call back Wordpress post title without echo

Comment: Then `$unity = get_the_title( $your_post_id )` should totally do the trick.